# XAMLParser-created DataTemplate: Correct way to reference a StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, xamlparseexception

I'm creating a DataTemplate in code using a XamlReader:

```
public DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate()
{
    string template = @"<DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel>        
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource=""{Binding Source={StaticResource collectibleTypeFromEnum}}"" />              
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>";

    ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
    context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]);
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");

    // This is meant to provide reference to where collectibleTypeFromEnum lives
    context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("myview", "MyProgram.View", "MyProgram, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("myview", "myview");

    return XamlReader.Parse(template, context) as DataTemplate;
}
```

The XAMLParser successfully parses the string and returns a DataTemplate, but it then crashes at runtime ('System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException': "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder'"). I need help providing the correct reference to that StaticResource, and I can't figure it out.

I'm *trying* to provide the correct namespace/reference via the ParserContext (see above), but clearly I'm doing it wrong. If I retrieve the ObjectDataProvider  from the XAML and add it to the Application's global resources instead (`Application.Current.Resources.Add()`) everything works. But it seems to me that I should be able to directly reference the XAML resource.

The converter in question is defined in a user control (the same one the DataTemplate initially lived in, so the DT had no problem finding it):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProgram.View.CollectibleDetail"
             [...] >
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="collectibleTypeFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="model:ECollectibleType"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: The full exception is this: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception." It's hard for me to get any additional information because I can't seem to catch the exception: it triggers off the ItemTemplateSelector of a ListBox (set in XAML) and happens in external code. I dunno how to wrap that in a try/catch block.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `collectibleTypeFromEnum` resource before returning the DataTemplate? Similiar to adding it to `Application.Current.Resources.Add()`, but just to the element you are returning.

Comment: "setting the collectibleTypeFromEnum resource" - can you be more specific? Set how?

Comment: Something like this:
`DataTemplate result = XamlReader.Parse(template, context) as DataTemplate;`
`result.Resources.Add("collectibleTypeFromEnum", objDataProvider);`
`return result;`

Comment: Good idea, but this still crashes: `ObjectDataProvider odp = element.FindResource("collectibleTypeFromEnum") as ObjectDataProvider;
   DataTemplate result = XamlReader.Parse(template, context) as DataTemplate;
   result.Resources.Add("collectibleTypeFromEnum", odp);`

Comment: Conversely, this is found: `Application.Current.Resources.Add("collectibleTypeFromEnum1", odp);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StaticResource` doesn't support forward referencing. You could either add the resource to `Application.Current.Resources` in order to make it available throughout your entire application or you could use `{DynamicResource}`:

```
string template = @"<DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>        
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource=""{DynamicResource collectibleTypeFromEnum}"" />              
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>";
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried DynamicResource instead, but it leads to another runtime exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Comment: Please check my answer again. You should not set the Source of a Binding to a DynamicResource. You should set the ItemsSource property itself to a DynamicResource.

Comment: I think your answer is technically correct (and I'll mark it as such), even though it doesn't solve my problem. If I change the ItemsSource to a DynamicResource without the binding, WPF expects that resource to be an actual collection of the values. It stops recognizing the ObjectDataProvider that should be invoked to provide the values, and consequently fails on the type: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'."

Comment: Oh, and I've resolved to adding these to the application's resource list instead for now, so my actual problem is kind of solved.